# How to update RadCartesianChart / ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, data-binding, telerik, windows-runtime, observablecollection

In my Windows 8 app I have a RadCartesianChart that looks like this:

```
<telerikChart:LineSeries ItemsSource="{Binding GraphData, Mode=TwoWay}" ShowLabels="True">
    <telerikChart:LineSeries.CategoryBinding>
        <telerikChart:PropertyNameDataPointBinding PropertyName="Category" />
    </telerikChart:LineSeries.CategoryBinding>
    <telerikChart:LineSeries.ValueBinding>
        <telerikChart:PropertyNameDataPointBinding PropertyName="Value" />
    </telerikChart:LineSeries.ValueBinding>
</telerikChart:LineSeries>
```

It is bound to this collection:

```
public ObservableCollection<Data> GraphData
{
    get { return _graphData; }
    set
    {
        if (_graphData != value)
        {
            _graphData = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => GraphData);
        }
    }
}
```

That contains these objects:

```
public class Data : ViewModelBase
{
    private string _category;
    private int _value;

    public string Category
    {
        get { return _category; }
        set
        {
            if (_category != value)
            {
                _category = value; 
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => Category);
            }
        }
    }

    //etc
}
```

The RadCartesianChart is bound to some default data, but I want to replace this data in runtime. But somehow I can't get this working... I already tried simply doing something like:

```
GraphData = new ObservableCollection<Data>(someData);
```

I tried doing something like this:

```
GraphData.Clear();
GraphData.Add(object1);
GraphData.Add(object2);
//etc
```

But the graph just won't update. I realize that this is possibly an ObservableCollection issue, but I can't get it working.

I am using the MVVM Light `ViewModelBase` btw. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: http://www.telerik.com/search.aspx?insection=True&start=0&client=telerik_developer_tools&q=RadCartesianChart%2bbinding&sid=1

Comment: @SynerCoder that's not really helpful.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14288030/lining-up-multiple-radcartesianchart-with-datetimecontinuousaxis/14288032#14288032) might help you out.

Comment: @klut I don't see how that is relevant. I'm doing something completely different.

Comment: Its actually pretty similar.  In both threads, we are trying to chart dynamic data.  You have to create a new LineSeries and setup your bindings in code, then add each LineSeries to your chart.  When I dig deeper into my project, I'll update a post and figure it out if you haven't already

Answer (score 4):

When the observable collection is changed it raises collection changed event which the  RadChart listens to, and it will update its UI. I have prepared you an example which references our Q1 2013 SDK. You can find it here - https://www.dropbox.com/s/1zv32gqsx1vryen/RadChartObsCollection.zip

Can you please clarify if this works properly on your side too and if not - what version of our controls you are using?